# Check to see if input is equal to text inside div

Tags: jquery, html, css, search-box

I am trying to build a search box that searches my site for text.  Right now I am trying to create a jquery keyup() function that takes input from my search box and compares it to text within two divs.  This code does not seem to be working the way I intend it when I type the div's text contents Tom or Randy into the search input. The result is console.log("nothing").

My Html

```
<input type="text" id="searchfor">

    <div class ="name"> Tom </div>
    <div class ="name"> Randy </div>
```

My jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('#searchfor').keyup(function(){

            $(".name").each(function(){
                    var $divText = $(".name").text().trim().toLowerCase();
                    var $searchInput = $("#searchfor").val().trim().toLowerCase();

                            if($searchInput === $divText) {
                           console.log("something");
                       }else{
                           console.log("nothing");
                       }


             });
      });
});
```

I want to know how I can get $searchInput to equal $divText so that when someone types Randy into the search input field the function will console.log("something"). Thank You

Comment: Looking at the values of your variables is a great place to start debugging when something isn't working correctly. If you do, you'll see that the value of $divText is "tomrandy". I'm sure that would at least have given you a hint of what's wrong, even before seeing [charlietfl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34889959/1082789).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `var $divText = $(".name").text();` will combine text of all the collection of elements.

Within your `each` you want the specific instance so use `$(this)`.

```
$('#searchfor').keyup(function() {
  // no need to get value in each iteration of loop...just store it here once
  var $searchInput = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase();

  // within loop `this` is instance of div.name
  $(".name").each(function() {
    var $divText = $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase();

    if ($searchInput === $divText) {
      console.log("something");
    } else {
      console.log("nothing");
    }

  });
});
```

This will only match if whole name is typed in.

If you only want partial match use `indexOf()`

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/x1gb2sey/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl .  That works well.  When you say indexOf() are you referring to ($searchInput === $divText.indexOf())   ? Is there a parameter I need to enter inside indexOf()?